# How to get Owner/sim number and Network Mode

Tags: android

I want to get the SIM number which currently in the phone i.e. owner number.
and network mode whether it is GSM or CDMA.

I search on net and try to do this by getLine1Number(); 
but gives nothing

Please help how can i do this.

Answer (score 7):

to get the number of ur SIM CARD , and the network u can do this :

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("MOBILE"))
            network = "cellnetwork/3G";
        else if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("WIFI"))
            network = "wifi";
        else 
            network ="na";

    uphone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

hope it hepls :)

i've tried it , and it works for me

Answer (score 3):

For the phone number you can do,

```
// Get the phone number from the telephony manager, and display it
TelephonyManager info = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = info.getLine1Number();
```

For the network mode, see [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

This question had been asked many times on SO.

See [How to get  the  mobile number of current sim card in real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206596/how-to-get-mobile-number-only-in-mobile-device-only)

And, I must add that getting the phone number depends on whether the carrier provided it on the SIM card or not.

Answer (score 0):

To get the phone number, try the TelephonyManager.

If that does not work you can get this info through AccountManager. One of the accounts will be the number.

See source details implementation on this post:
[TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/get-phone-number-problem/10255465#10255465)