# Android phone number

Tags: android, android-layout

The following code does not give me the phone number of the device ,how can i get the phone number

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Telephone number: "+ number,
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

ALso i have tried the following..but the number doest show up

[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

[How to get  the  mobile number of current sim card in real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206596/how-to-get-mobile-number-only-in-mobile-device-only)

Comment: Have you inserted a SIM? What *does* it return?

Comment: this number is not always aviliable. For example, some prepaid card don't have number stored in the sim.

Comment: Yes i have inserted a SIM and is not a prepaid card..

Answer (score 2):

The only method available from Android API as all the comments suggest is *getLine1Number()*. However I have never been able to obtain it since your operator must provide you with a SIM that supports letting phone read internal phone number. That seems not very common, so I am afraid that you could be left without means of knowing it.

That's why some programs that use your phone number to identify you (i.e. Whatsapp) do ask user about his/her phone number, because there is no sure way to getting it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

the code provided:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

should work fine, however, it will not if you forgot the permission "READ_PHONE_STATE".

Hope this works now :)

Comment: then im afraid i have no idea what's wrong, unless you could show some DMS logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
    }
```

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

**[In case if anyone still stumbles here looking for this still existing age-old problem]**

AFAIK, TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() is not reliable due to various constraints from operators.
There are some java reflection based hacks but varies from device to device thus making those hacks sort of useless [at least in terms of supported models]

But there is a legitimate lawful logic to find the number, if you really need so. Query all the SMS by sms provider and get the "To" number.

Extra benefits of this trick: 1. you can get all the line numbers if there is multi sim in the device.

Cons: 1. you will need SMS_READ permission [sorry for that]
 2. You will get all the sim numbers ever used in the device. this problem can be minimised with some constraint logic e.g. time frame (sms received or sent only today) etc. It would be  interesting to hear from others about how to improve this case.