# How to show user mobile number into a textbox in android?

Tags: android, mobile, phone-number

I have a textBox(EditText1) in android (Vs-2.3.3)

I want to show my own mobile number (provided my sim is not changed) into the text box.

Is That possible?

Please give the source code if that possible.

Please also tell me what are the prerequisites if possible.

Note : I want to show my own mobile number only , not from contacts.

Comment: what you want to display your contact detail?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow isn't really a "give me teh codez" kind of site. Please actually try some code first, then come back and ask questions. Read [ask]. If you have tried coding something, then post it along with any errors you are receiving.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206596/how-to-get-the-mobile-number-in-real-device

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Phone Number in Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 0):

use TelephonyManager  for getting your own mobile number as:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String strmobinum= tm.getLine1Number();
edttxt.setText(strmobinum);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: any permissions do i need to give?

Comment: yes add  `<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` permission in AndroidManifest

Comment: @ It is giving mobile number as null

Comment: @divaNilisha Read the link, I commented on your question.

Comment: THIS REALLY SOLVED..IT IS ACTUALLY MENAT FOR SIM AND CUG NUMBERS. I CHANGED THE SIM AND WORKED.

Comment: @divaNilisha : why you unaccpet my answer?