# Get mobile Number on GSM Mobile using android code

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am using following android code to get mobile number and it's working on android emulators only:

```
TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

But when I tested it in real device (`Samsung Galaxy Chat B5330`) it gives nothing (Empty String)

Please help with some code snippet.

Comment: Probably have to use USSD code from the local carrier, not sure but am also interested to know!

Comment: It depends on the SIM card. You can find a useful answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5134725/2198638.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GSM, the phone number is on the SIM card, and some carriers just don't put it on the card, and then the phone does not know what it is, but in this case you 
should get an empry string rather than a null

if the carrier stores the number on your SIM, go to `Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> My phone Number`. If it displays `unknown` there, then your number is not stored on the SIM.

[image]

get IMEI use:

```
TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
imei_no = tm.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: Ya its showing unknown....is there any other way to get mobile number (by using sim card number or IMEI)??

Comment: i dont think there is other way.. because its all depend on mobile carriers company(like vodaphone...etc) mean they don't give us mobile number then how we get it..

Answer (score 1):

Add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2207427/1051147)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Telephony Manager;If at all you not found the contact no. of user;
You can get Sim Serial Number of Sim Card and Imei No. of Android Device by using the same Telephony Manager Class...

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Import:

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
```

Use the below code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

         // get IMEI
         imei = tm.getDeviceId();

         // get SimSerialNumber
         simSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```