# How to get cell phone number in android?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

How to get cell phone number in android ?
Here is code. but it's not working

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mobileno = tm.getLine1Number();
```

can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get mobile Number on GSM Mobile using android code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333816/get-mobile-number-on-gsm-mobile-using-android-code)

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar that's rather poor choice for marking duplicate. [The top voted one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone?lq=1) have much better explanations.

Comment: Define "not working."

Answer (score 1):

You can use these lines of code to fetch cell phone numbers from your phone contacts picker.

```
try {
Intent i = new     Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT);
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d("TAG", "Pick Contact ERROR" + e.toString());
}
```

and use OnActivityResult to get contacts and save it anywhere you want (Like this)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
Uri contactUri = data.getData();
cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String PhoneNumber =     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
String ContactName =     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
```

Comment: your answer appreciable. but i want number programatically.

Comment: Can you tell me that you want to choose contact from contact picker or not..???  and explain your problem somewhat more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String number = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

And for this code to work you need Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya what are you getting?

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya If you get null, you could display something to get the user to input the phone number on his/her own.